# How to switch from GUI to CLI mode and terminate any GUI program?

Tags: command-line, gui

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit.  I need to perform some database benchmarks on my computer so I want to make it in strict terminal mode, without desktop.  I know I can `ctrl-alt-f1` to go to terminal mode, but there is still graphical desktop running in background. (Using CPU and RAM which I do not want it to).

So please help me to kill all graphical components and switch to only terminal mode (for better performance). I will not need multiple users to be able to log in and do not need to have networking (all benchmarks will be on `localhost` interface).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command below will stop the graphical interface.  The next one will restart it for you (everything will be reset as if you had restarted your computer).

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo service lightdm start
```

This works for Unity, I don't know for sure if it works on Gnome desktop.

Comment: This works if your display manager is _lightdm_ (which is probably the case unless you explicitly changed it). Other display managers are _gdm3_ and _kdm_ (for KDE). In that case, just replace `lightdm` with `gdm3` or `kdm` in the given commands, correspondingly.

Comment: Ok thanks, that clears things up for me.  Display manager, not GUI.  It's been a long week of studying shell scripting, I forgot my graphical rules.

Answer (score 1):

To stop any Desktop Manager/Window Manager, for Kubuntu/KDE:

```
sudo service kdm stop
```

For GNOME3:

```
sudo service gdm stop
```

For Lubuntu/LXDE:

```
sudo service lxdm stop
```

For Xubuntu/XFCE:

```
sudo service xdm stop
```

To start everything again, just replace `stop` for `start`. You can also try switching from init level to #1.

Comment: Great, now how about starting them? ;P

Comment: @Seth if you `stop` something the contrary is to `start` something, no?